# DocsListDialog examples

Tags: google-apps-script

Still fairly new to google app scripts and saw a great class with crappy documentation.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslistdialog.  I'm hoping to use this to allow my users to select a document from their Google collection.

Here's what I've started:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(400).setWidth(600);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var doclisthandler = app.createServerHandler('selectionhandler');
var doclist = app.createDocsListDialog().showDocsPicker().addSelectionHandler(doclisthandler); 
ss.show(app);}

function selectionhandler(e)
{    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var selname = e.parameter.doclist;           
toastDoc.toast(selname,'here in selectionhandler',4);
return app;
}
```

My toastDoc.toast is just to verify my selectionhandler function works and see what is returned.  selname  returns 'undefined'.

I've looked for examples on this class other than what's in the url from above, but I got nothing :(

Ideally, I'd like to return the document id that is selected so that my script can do further processing...

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check what it returns, you can use below function. Everything will be returned in Logger

```
function selectionhandler(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter.items[0].id);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.items[0].name);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.items[0].url);
//Or to check everything which is returned in e.parameter
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return app;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Waqar, that did it.
How did you know to use .id  .name and .url ? Is that documented somewhere?  Would love to know so I can learn more !

Comment: To check what it returns, Just Log the 'e' which is passed to the handler function e.g Logger.log(e), or Logger.log(e.parameter) and After invoking the handler function, check the log

Comment: I got that part :)   I was just curious how you **knew** that was what needed to happen.  Is that a Google-thing?  java-thing?

Thanks !

Comment: To know more about it, You may go through this discussion "http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps-script/getting-started/6UgZnj9kyLQ"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to add a callback element to your handler...

```
addCallbackElement(name);
```

regards,
Serge

EDIT :
Hi Joe,
I'm also working on something like this... I thought it could be interesting to show what I have so far... not finished yet ;-)
I paste the whole thing so you can esily test it:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Doclist UI", functionName: "doclistUI"},

                    ];
  ss.addMenu("Utilities", menuEntries);//
}
//
function doclistUI(){
  var folderlist = new Array();
  var folders=DocsList.getFolders()
  for(ff=0;ff<folders.length;++ff){
    folderlist.push(folders[ff].getName());
    }
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(260).setWidth(700).setStyleAttribute('background', 'beige')
      .setStyleAttribute("position", "relative").setStyleAttribute("left", "10").setStyleAttribute("top", "12px");
  app.setTitle("Doclist UI");
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var hpanel2 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var Flist= app.createListBox(false).setName("Flb").setId("Flb").setVisibleItemCount(4).setWidth("180");
  var Dlist= app.createListBox(false).setName("Dlb").setId("Dlb").setVisibleItemCount(8).setWidth("280");
  var Flab=app.createLabel('Folder List').setWidth("80");
  var Dlab=app.createLabel('Document List').setWidth("100");
  var spacer=app.createLabel(' ').setWidth("30");
  var spacer2=app.createLabel(' ').setWidth("15");
//  
  Flist.addItem('Choose a folder');
  for(ff=0;ff<folderlist.length;++ff){
    Flist.addItem(folderlist[ff]);
  }
  var anchor = app.createAnchor('open ', "www.google.com").setId('anchor').setVisible(false);
  hpanel.add(Flab).add(Flist).add(spacer).add(Dlab).add(Dlist)
  var docname = app.createLabel().setId('doc').setSize("360", "40");
  hpanel2.add(anchor).add(spacer2).add(docname);
  var dwnld = app.createButton("Download").setId("dwnld");
  panel.add(hpanel).add(hpanel2).add(dwnld);
//
  var FHandler = app.createServerHandler("click");
  Flist.addChangeHandler(FHandler)
  FHandler.addCallbackElement(hpanel);
//
  var DHandler = app.createServerHandler("showlab");
  Dlist.addChangeHandler(DHandler);
  DHandler.addCallbackElement(hpanel);
//
  var keyHandler = app.createServerHandler("download");
  dwnld.addClickHandler(keyHandler)
  keyHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
//
  app.add(panel);  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
  }
//
function click(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var Dlist = app.getElementById("Dlb");  
   var label = app.getElementById('doc')
   var folderName = e.parameter.Flb
       if (folderName=='Choose a folder'){Dlist.clear();label.setText(" ");return app}
   var doclist=new Array();
   doclist=DocsList.getFolder(folderName).getFiles(0,2000)
    if(doclist.length==0){Dlist.clear();Dlist.addItem(' No files');return app}
   var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
  names.sort();
  Dlist.clear();
  for(dd=0;dd<names.length;++dd){
    Dlist.addItem(names[dd][0]+" (doc Nr:"+dd+")");
  }
return app   ;// update UI
}
//
function showlab(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var label = app.getElementById('doc')
  var link = app.getElementById('anchor')
  var Dlist = app.getElementById("Dlb");  
  var folderName = e.parameter.Flb
  var docname = e.parameter.Dlb
  var doclist=new Array();
  Logger.log(doclist.length)
  doclist=DocsList.getFolder(folderName).getFiles(0,2000)
    if(doclist.length==0){return app}
  var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
   names.sort();
   var filename = e.parameter.Dlb
   var ID= Number(filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(":")+1).replace(")",""));  
   var docN = docname.substr(0,docname.lastIndexOf("("))
   label.setText(docN).setEnabled(false).setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '15')
   link.setVisible(true).setHref("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key="+names[ID][1]+"#gid=0");
   return app   ;// update UI
}
//
function download(e){ // this part not implemented yet :-/
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var Dlist = app.getElementById("Dlb");  
   var folderName = e.parameter.Flb
   var doclist=new Array();
   doclist=DocsList.getFolder(folderName).getFiles(0,2000)
   var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
   names.sort();
// 
   var filename = e.parameter.Dlb
   var ID= Number(filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(":")+1).replace(")",""));  

  Browser.msgBox(names[ID][1])
return app   ;// update UI
}
//eof
```

Comment: I think this is not required for the DocsListDialog

Comment: Hi Serge,  nice to see you over here :)

The code that Waqar showed does indeed return the values I needed.  However, the code above is being called from this code:
`var MyFileBtnhandler = app.createServerClickHandler('doclistdialog').addCallbackElement(lbavailSheets);`

with lbavailSheets an element on the parent page.  Should there be something different as a CallBackelement?  I don't see how to get the value I want back to the parent for processing.

Comment: Note : the script I just posted shows only spreadsheets, as I said, it's a 'work in progress' ;-)

Comment: Very nice Serge..  I'm looking to try to utilize the new DocsListDialog feature to select the spreadsheet.  Something to think about would be installing Google Drive and saving the document into a particular folder that is synch'd.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you have in mind... can you explain ?